# Transfer function as props between React Components

Tags: reactjs

everyone! Could someone, please, explain me what's wrong with **this** in line *hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay={() => this.hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay()}*. Because of that I have an error **Cannot read property 'hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay' of undefined**.

```
class OrderBlockTemplate extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showOrderDetailClick = this.showOrderDetailClick.bind(this);
    //...other code
    this.state = {
        showOrderDetails : false,
        orderData : orderFullData,
        showDarkOverlay : false
    };
}

showOrderDetailClick() {
    let {showOrderDetails} = this.state;
    this.setState({
        showOrderDetails : !showOrderDetails,
        showDarkOverlay : true
    });
}

hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay() {
    this.setState({
        showOrderDetails : false,
        showDarkOverlay : false
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid orderBlockTemplate">
            <div className="orderBlockWrapper">

                {/* other code */}

            </div>

            {/*Show DarkOverlay Component if "orderBlockDetailButton" is clicked*/}
            {this.state.showOrderDetails ? <DarkOverlay/> : ""}

            {/*Show OrderDetails Component if "orderBlockDetailButton" is clicked.
            And transfer order data into OrderDetailsBlock*/}
            {this.state.showOrderDetails ? 
                this.state.orderData.map(function(item, i) {
                    return(
                        <OrderDetails key={i} 
                                    item={item}
                                    hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay={() => this.hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay()}
                        />
                    );
                }) : ""
            }                

        </div>

    );        
}
}

export default OrderBlockTemplate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost the reference to the right `this` on this line:

```
this.state.orderData.map(function(item, i) {
```

You can change it to use a fat arrow to preserve it:

```
this.state.orderData.map((item, i) => {
```

Or explicitly pass `this` as the second argument to orderData.map:

```
this.state.orderData.map(function(item, i) {
    // ...
}, this)
```

The [`Array.prototype.map()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) explain this behaviour.

---

Bear in mind that you don't need a fat arrow here:

```
hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay={() => this.hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay()}
```

You can avoid it by either binding in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    // ...
    this.hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay = this.hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay.bind(this);
}
```

Or by declaring the function with a fat arrow:

```
hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay = () => {
```

Using either of these two methods would allow you to write:

```
hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay={this.hideOrderDetailsAndDarkOverlay}
```

Which means that a new anonymous function isn't created on every call to `render`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped